# ResourceLockedError: Object "some object" is locked via WebDAV

Tags: plone-5.x

I cant rename or delete object at folder_contents view.

And I cant rename object at ZMI.

And I restart plone, then cant do that.

What's happening?

```
2017-11-01 07:51:08 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1509522668.230.243665353476 http://127.0.0.1:8086/Plone/en/manage_delObjects
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module plone.dexterity.content, line 707, in manage_delObjects
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 536, in manage_delObjects
ResourceLockedError: Object "rss-feed" is locked via WebDAV
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is what you forget push cancel button.

- Goto current page. http://127.0.0.1:8086/Plone/en/rss-feed
- Edit current object. http://127.0.0.1:8086/Plone/en/rss-feed/edit
- Push cancel button.

Push cancel button always!

before move to other page, or close browser window.

https://community.plone.org/t/dexterity-webdav-option-appears-to-have-a-problem/1564/4